# How do you call a function in the parent page from a child page within a frame?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a page (called `MainPage`) that has a frame in it containing an instance of a child page (called `EditorPage`). How can the child page instance call a `public` function in the parent page?

Comment: The UI should not call any methods. ViewModels should, so you'd not really care about how your UI is structured, if you properly structured your ViewModel layer. in WPF, UI is not the application, ViewModels are, UI is just a nice way to interact with those ViewModels (I.E the Application)

Answer (score 3):

Not pretty but you can pass a reference in the ctor

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Page1 page1 = new Page1(this);
        Frame1.Navigate(page1);
    }
    public void MainMethod() {}
}


public partial class Page1 : Page
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Page1(MainWindow mw)
    {
        mw.MainMethod();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Consider just adding Class to the project to hold shared methods

Comment: If `MainMethod()` was a function that altered the `MainWindow` UI, would it work when being called in `Page1`?

Comment: What have you tried?  The stated question is public function in the parent page.